# Flooring multiple rooms

Tags: flooring, transition

The photo attached shows both vinyl/ laminate flooring and carpet. My plan is to rip out carpet and install new vinyl flooring right on top of existing hardwood floors. Once I rip out carpet the carpet room won't be same height. Is the best option T- molding or 3/4 osb subfloor or just ripping out the old hardwood? Using the same vinyl through out the house and think it would look better with no T-mold.

[image: Photo]

Comment: The carpet now seems higher, so new vinyl floor over everything?

Comment: I personaly would not rip out the hardwood floor, to keep the possibility for a future remodel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally even luxury vinyl plank has expansion requirements and typically sets maximum room widths.  You'd probably end up with a T molding separating the rooms.  Now if you are asking about a reducing molding that steps down to a different floor height then I'd try to avoid that.

Check the instructions on your specific product to see what maximum they specify sometimes you can go over the maximum by increasing the room left for expansion in which case maybe you can avoid a molding entirely which is going to be the best look.

What installation type are you planning? floating or glue down?

Comment: Looking to instal floating. Lifeproof states that max area is 100x100ft to install without transition.

Comment: Late to the game but if the subfloor is going to be the same height for the carpet and the hardwood - I'd just rip out the hardwood - no real advantage in keeping it that I can  think of.  Also the homedepot lifeproof is terrible compared to duraclic from lowes - I've installed both.  How did it go?

Answer (score -1):

If it’s hardwood underneath just refinish it.

Comment: This doesn't address the question posed.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question asked, but it's a good answer!